# How to repair toilet flange that is glued and recessed

Tags: flange

I installed new flooring. The existing toilet flange is recessed - see picture. The flange is glued into and existing outlet and I don’t see a way of removing it without cutting the pipe lower down and making a new outlet. An alternative is to cut the top of the flange and add a new flange with a smaller outlet - there are flanges that fit within a 3 inch outlet.
Would this work?
Also, would I need to build up the subfloor or can I still have it recessed?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is wrong with the flange itself. How far down is the top of the flange from the new floor?

Comment: About 0.5 inch from top of flange to top of new floor.. I used a large wax seal before and it worked well..

Answer (score 3):

Your original flange looks like it's in perfectly good condition, so I wouldn't try to remove & replace it.
Instead, I would use a [Flange Spacer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-1-4-in-PVC-Flange-Spacer-435192/303864021?MERCH=REC-_-NavPLPHorizontal1_rr-_-NA-_-303864021-_-N) like this:
[image]

or one of [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-Toilet-Flange-Spacer-Kit-Includes-All-4-Spacer-Sizes-43406/305537816):
[image]

Comment: I would disagree it is way to far below the surface to make a seal with even a 2 seal hack!

Comment: @EdBeal - the OP says in a comment that it's only recessed a 1/2", and a "large wax seal" worked previously...

Answer (score 0):

A half inch of space isn't very much. You can probably use a normal size wax seal and be fine or you can go with a extra thick seal to be sure it seals properly.